# Task seems to be registered but is not able to run?

Tags: node.js, frameworks, gulp

I'm trying to build my framework so that it's more robust and re-usable.

```
/gulp-framework
    tasks/
        _assets.js
    index.js
    package.json
    node_modules/
/project-a
    gulpfile.js
    configuration.js
```

Within `index.js` I am using `require(./tasks/_assets.js)(gulp, config)`;

I have a console log inside `_assets.js` and I can see that in the output, if I run gulp -T I get the response:

```
[08:17:44] ├── assets
[08:17:44] ├── build
[08:17:44] └─┬ default
[08:17:44]   └── build
```

Build simply runs assets using `run-sequence()`. Obviously the task is registered here, however if I just run `gulp` in cmd, I get:

```
Starting 'build'...
[08:18:19] 'build' errored after 1.76 ms
[08:18:19] Error: Task assets is not configured as a task on gulp.  If this is a submodule, you may need to use require('run-sequence').use(gulp).
```

I've tried using use gulp but that just creates more errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I since found out that the module `run-sequence` is telling me exactly what I needed to do, although I didn't realise that this was specific to the `run-sequence` module.

Whereever I'm using `run-sequence` in a sub-module I needed to do the following:

```
module.exports = function(gulp, config) {
    var runSequence = require('run-sequence').use(gulp);
}
```

From [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence):

**Using within gulp submodules**

*if you have a complex gulp setup with your tasks split up across different files, you may get the error that run-sequence is unable to find your tasks. In this case, you can configure run-sequence to look at the gulp within the submodule, like so:*

```
// submodule tasks/mygulptask.js 
var gulp = require('gulp'), 
// might be a different instance than the toplevel one 
// this uses the gulp you provide 
runSequence = require('run-sequence').use(gulp);
// ...and then use normally 
runSequence('subtask1', 'subtask2');
```